# Why does the former work but the latter doesn't?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

The following MWE works well:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title={This is a title},hbox]
    This is a body.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

However, the following **cannot be compiled** with TeX Live 2018 XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{TColorBox}[1]{\begin{tcolorbox}[title=#1,hbox]}
{\end{tcolorbox}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{TColorBox}{This is a title}
    This is a body.
    \end{TColorBox}
\end{document}
```

**Why does the former work but the latter doesn't?**

**What's the root cause?**

Comment: I've not tried, but my guess is the second becomes `title=This is a title`.  Have you tried `[title={#1},hbox]` in your newenvironment?

Comment: I have tried, but no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message that you are getting is

> LaTeX Error: \begin{tcolorbox} on input line 6 ended by \end{TColorBox}.

This is a standard problem that you get when you try to define a new environment that contains another environment, essentially because LaTeX gets confused about which environment it needs to close next. One work around is to use:

```
\newenvironment{TColorBox}[1]{\tcolorbox[title=#1,hbox]}{\endtcolorbox}
```

which works because the `TColorBox` environment does not open another environment. However, I think that the "correct" way to do what you want is to use `\newtcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{TColorBox}[1]{title=#1,hbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{TColorBox}{This is a title}
    This is a body.
  \end{TColorBox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]